# PHP MySQL check if request have ' # ' char insert a new row

Tags: php, mysql

I Have some request like below :

```
$input  = "$POS,1234,5223,A,2719";
```

If get a request like above , process an save to database with below code :

```
$input_ex = explode(",", $input);

$input_ex[0];
$input_ex[1];
$input_ex[2];
$input_ex[3];
$input_ex[4];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name (cl_1,cl_2,cl_3,cl_4,cl_5)
values ('$input_ex[0]','$input_ex[1]','$input_ex[2]','$input_ex[3]','$input_ex[4]')
```

***Problem:***
my inputs may be sometimes more than one and split with ' # ' character
last row of inputs is maybe have ' # ' character too

```
$input  = "$POS,1234,5223,A,2719#
$POX,752,4342,N,SXD#
$POZ,122,6242,B,XFB#";
```

***How*** can i separate each row and insert it on database as a new row ?
thanks ;)

***edit :*** 
inputs is 3 different mode , 1st is a one row without any `#` sign , 2nd is have more row with end `#`  on last row , 3th more row without `#` sign on end of last row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (explode('#', $input) as $record) {
  $record = trim($record);

  if ($record == '')
    continue;

  $input_ex = explode(',', $record);

  $input_ex[0];
  $input_ex[1];
  $input_ex[2];
  $input_ex[3];
  $input_ex[4];

  // Same MySQL query as you already have
  mysql_query("...");
}
```

Comment: inputs is 3 different mode , 1st is a one row without any `#` sign , 2nd is have more row with end `#`  on last row , 3th more row without `#` sign on end of last row

Comment: Or `foreach(preg_split("/\s*#\s*/mS",$input) as $record)`, no need to `trim` every record.

Answer (score 0):

first explode by '#', and for each result explode by ',' and add new row

Comment: can give a example ? inputs is 3 different mode , 1st is a one row without any `#` sign , 2nd is have more row with end `#`  on last row , 3th more row without `#` sign on end

Answer (score 0):

Just explode on the '#" first, then loop through the array of results exploding on "," as you are doing and making an insert for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `explode()` twice.  First to check for multiple records and then once more to split on the delimiter `,`:

```
<?php  
$input  = "POS,1234,5223,A,2719# POX,752,4342,N,SXD# POZ,122,6242,B,XFB#";

foreach(explode('#', $input) as $records){
    $record = explode(',', $records);
    print_r($record);
}
?>
```